# How to efficiently UPDATE a column when it requires joining 2 large tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update

I've got 2 tables, named: `csv (a csv dump)`, and `items (primary data table)` with 7M (csv dump) and 15M rows respectively. I need to update a column in `items` that exists in table `csv`.

Both tables have a commonly indexed join ID (a `VARCHAR(255)`).

An UPDATE query with a join on the mutual ID column (indexed) still takes multiple days to run. After researching it  I believe the inefficiency is in MySQL scanning the `csv` table and making per-row random-access queries against the `items` table.

Even though there are indexes, those indexes don't fit in memory, so the required 7M random access queries are nose diving performance.

Are there "typical" ways of addressing this kind of issue?

---

**Update:**

> We're basically taking multiple catalogs of "items" and storing them
>   in our `items` table (this is bit of a simplification for discussion).
>   Each of say 10 catalogs will have 7M items (some duplicates across catalogs that we
>   normalize to 1 row in our item table). We need to compare and
>   verify changes to those 10 catalogs daily (`UPDATES` w/ joins between two big
>   tables, or other such mechanism).
>
> In reality we have an `items` table and an `items_map` table, but no
>   need to discuss that additional level of abstraction here. I'd be
>   happy to find a way to perform an update between the `csv` dump table
>   and an `items` table (given that they both have a common ID that's
>   indexed in both tables). But  given that the `items` table might have
>   20M rows, and the `csv` table might have 7M rows.
>
> In this case indexes don't fit in memory and we're hammering the drive with random seeks I believe

Comment: can you please explain your problem with structure and data so that we are relly get to know

Comment: I've added my update to the question describing our use case in more detail.

Comment: May we take it that the join-able field is indexed in both tables ?  Can we see your update statement ?  Also - do you know that every record in the csv has a corresponding item record ?

Comment: `In reality we have an items table and an items_map table, but no need to discuss that additional level of abstraction here.` IMHO this question would have been answerable if you had supplied the real schema instead of this texstual explanation. It could be your abstraction was wrong, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally put this query to an 8 core box with 12 GB of ram dedicated to InnoDB and it did completed but after 7 hours!

Our solution: We're moving this process off of MySQL. We'll use MapReduce (Hadoop) to maintain the entire large table in flat file format, do the major update processes in parallel and then finally use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to update the table once quickly (~daily).